# Calling custom functions from firebug console

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, console, firebug

I created a document that loads a .js document that has some JQuery functions that I have created. I would like to use the firebug console to quickly test the functionality of these functions on my html document.  But when I try and call these function in the console I don't get any response.

for example:

- I have index.html that call my JS:

  ```
  <script src="jquery.js" type"text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="myfunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  ```
- Myfuntions.js has the following defined in it:

  ```
  function showAbout(){
    $('div#about').show("slow");
    $('.navbar #about-button').attr('disabled', true); 
  }
  ```

The Problem:

When i try to call `showAbout` or `showAbout()`  from the console on  index.html I don't get any  changes. However, when I call `$('div#about').show("slow");` or `$('div#about').show("slow");` from the console directly I get the expected behavior.
What is the proper way to call a user defined function from the console?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If `showAbout` is defined at the global scope, you should be able to write `showAbout();` in the console and see the result. If not, then you're probably putting your functions in a *scoping function* like so:

```
(function() {
    function showAbout() {
    }
})();
```

If so, **good for you**, you've avoided created global variables/functions. But it does mean you can't access those functions from the console, because the console only has access to global scope.

If you want to export any of those so you can use them from the console (perhaps only temporarily, for debugging), you can do that like this:

```
(function() {
    window.showAbout = showAbout;
    function showAbout() {
    }
})();
```

That explicitly puts a `showAbout` property on the global object (`window`) referencing your function. Then `showAbout();` in the console will work.

Comment: why is wrapping the function in parenthesis followed by another set of parenthesis mandatory to make this work?  **(** function(){ ... } **)()** ;

Comment: @Ricalsin: The parentheses, per se, aren't required, but *something* is, because we need to help the parser understand that it's dealing with a function *expression* rather than a function *declaration*, because you can invoke a function expression immediately by putting `()` at the end, but you can't invoke a function *declaration* that way. More in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13341698/157247) and my answer to it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your `showAbout()` probably isn't in the global scope.

It may be wrapped by a `$(document).ready()` code, and its scope limited to that function.

For testing, you could add beneath...

```
window.showAbout = showAbout;
```

You can then call `showAbout()` from your console, once the function has been defined.