# JavaScript plus sign in front of function expression

Tags: javascript, function, operators, iife, self-invoking-function

I’ve been looking for information about immediately invoked functions, and somewhere I stumbled on this notation:

```
+function(){console.log("Something.")}()
```

Can someone explain to me what the `+` sign in front of the function means/does?

Comment: Ben Alman explains it all here: http://mths.be/iife

Comment: related: [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3755606/1048572)

Answer (score 1360, accepted):

It forces the parser to treat the part following the `+` as an expression. This is usually used for functions that are invoked immediately, e.g.:

```
+function() { console.log("Foo!"); }();
```

Without the `+` there, if the parser is in a state where it's expecting a statement (which can be an expression or several non-expression statements), the word `function` looks like the beginning of a function *declaration* rather than a function *expression* and so the `()` following it (the ones at the end of the line above) would be a syntax error (as would the absense of a name, in that example). *With* the `+`, it makes it a function expression, which means the name is optional and which results in a reference to the function, which can be invoked, so the parentheses are valid.

`+` is just one of the options. It can also be `-`, `!`, `~`, or just about any other unary operator. Alternately, you can use parentheses (this is more common, but neither more nor less correct syntactically):

```
(function() { console.log("Foo!"); })();
// or
(function() { console.log("Foo!"); }());
```

Comment: More elaboration is here, http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Can't we say that the paren-wrapping is a superior notation? I'm VERY familiar with parens serving to encompass expressions. It's not clear at all what + is doing in this case if you don't already know this arcane quirk of js.

Comment: Note: Of the two parens options, **jsLint** prefers the second one. I think **jsHint** is less fussy.

Comment: One of the commonly used libraries that uses the "plus" notation is [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) (which is how I ended up reading this thread).

Comment: Bootstrap is doing this, btw:
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js

Comment: *But when I say "correct" above, I mean syntactically, not in a broader sense.* As @Beetroot-Beetroot points out, in the narrowly broader sense of [JSLint, parens are, in fact, correcter](http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2011/02/17/jslint-messages-wrap-an-immediate-function-invocation-in-parentheses/). ;^)

Answer (score 102):

Subsidiary to @TJCrowder's answer, `+` is usually used to force numerical casting of a value [as this SO answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators). In this instance it is called the 'unary plus operator' (for ease of googling).

```
var num = +variant;
```

So in front of a function it can be a way to force the function's result to be interpreted as a number. I doubt it happens yet, but theoretically the JIT could use that to compile the function as a numerical-only function etc. However, to prevent the unary plus being a concatenation when used in a larger expression, you would need parentheses:

```
blah + (+(function(){ var scope; return "4"; })());
```

Comment: How did this ever get 37 upvotes? The `(+function() { ... })()` notation can never execute without errors (apart from the fact that this doesn't answer the question).

Comment: @whitequark: Missed a pair of braces around the function+call. Suspect the upvotes were more because of the number casting explanation.

Comment: OK I might have been nitpicking.

Comment: You have some unnecessary brackets there, it is completely sufficient to do this: `3 + +function(){ return "4"; }();`

Comment: @Christoph I'd be inclined to leave those brackets there. In fact, I would go so far as to add them if they were missing. It makes it much more clear what is going on, and also prevents issues when the code is minimized by removing the spaces, leading to `3++function...` which is not the same.

Comment: Although on further reflection, the `+function...` is unnecessary in itself.  The same result can be had with `blah + function( ){ ... }( );` which would negate the need for the wrapping brackets.

Answer (score 65):

So the short answer is that it prevents a syntax error, by using the function results in one way or another.

You can also instruct the engine that you're not even interested in the return value by using the `void` operator:

```
void function() { console.log("Foo!"); }();
```

Of course, putting braces around the whole thing also serves that purpose.

Comment: Void or parentheses are *immensely* preferable. They are WTF-free. Using + is the sort of cleverness that isn't very smart.

Comment: A good point. It seems like using one of the operators would move against what is presently industry standard. Perhaps "cool kid" developers would opt for it, otherwise I'm still not seeing a point of using something rather than void or ()

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR (Quick Answer)

[`Plus Sign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) Casts (Converts) the proceeding operand to a Number if it isn't already.

## Solution & Origins

The `+` sign before the function, actually called [Unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) and is part of a group called a [Unary Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#unary_operators) and (the Unary Plus) is used to convert string and other representations to numbers (integers or floats).

> A unary operation is an operation with only one operand, i.e. a single
> input. This is in contrast to binary operations, which use two
> operands

### Basic Uses:

```
const x = "1";
const y = "-1";
const n = "7.77";

console.log(+x);
// expected output: 1

console.log(+n);
// expected output: 7.77

console.log(+y);
// expected output: -1

console.log(+'');
// expected output: 0

console.log(+true);
// expected output: 1

console.log(+false);
// expected output: 0

console.log(+'hello');
// expected output: NaN
```

When the `+` sign is positioned before a variable, function or any returned string representations the output will be converted to integer or float; the unary operator (`+`) converts as well the non-string values `true`, `false`, and `null`.

### Advanced Uses

The right way to use the function you mentioned above will be:

```
+function(){return "3.141"}()
// expected output: 3.141
```

I love to use `+` to turn a `new Date()` object to a **timestamp**, like this:

```
+new Date()
// expected output: 1641387991035
```

### Other Unary Operators

> `-` The unary negation operator converts its operand to Number type
> and then negates it.
>
> `~` Bitwise NOT operator.
>
> `!` Logical NOT operator.
>
> `delete` The delete operator deletes a property from an object.
>
> `void` The void operator discards an expression's return value.
>
> `typeof` The typeof operator determines the type of a given object.

Comment: The unary `+` operator's *side-effect* is that it coerces its argument to number. This is in my opinion quite counter-intuitive, especially considering that binary `+` operator, for instance, also performs string concatenation. So `'hello' + 'world'` becomes `'helloworld'` but `+'hello'` becomes `NaN`, rather than `'hello'` which would be the result of concatenation with an empty string.