# JavaScript: ! need to understand its function(not())

Tags: javascript

I have the following two codes set. The first alerts 'true', I know that, Its Ok. The second one alerts 'false', I thought that would alert '`!function(){return false}`'. But, It alerts 'false'. How this second code block alerts `false`? Could anyone help me understand that please?

```
var myVar = !function(){return false}();
alert(myVar);   //true 
var myVar = !function(){return false};
alert(myVar);  //false, I dont understand this, how false can come?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question already has a nice answer from Amit joki

I had read a comment below his answer there the questioner was said that he need more explanation that's why i am posting  this answer .

**First Case:**

```
var myVar = !function(){ return false; }( );

alert(myVar);
```

Here **myVar is an anonymous function** and through the below code **it calls itself.**

```
var myVar = !function(){ return false; }( );
```

> That is it, is a self executing anonymous function!

.

> a `!function()` Using the ! operator before the function causes it to
>   be treated as an expression, so we can call it:

So when we try to `alert(myvar);`

then it will alert the return value of the `myVar` function . Already the `myVar` function return a `false` and the `!` symbol in our code will convert it to `true`

So it will return `true`

Think our code is something like below

```
var myVar = function(){ return 10; }( );
```

it will also alert `true`. Because in javascript only `false, NaN, null, undefined, 0 , ""` are false and other all are `truth`.

and when the above code changes to

```
var myVar = !function(){ return 10; }( );
```

then it will alert `false` because the statement `return 10` is  true in javascript  and it will converted to `false` by `!` `operator`

**Then in second case :**

```
var myVar = !function(){return true};

alert(myVarz);
```

Here is no self executing anonymous function. only an anonymous  function definition is here. When we try `alert(myVar)`

`myVar` is now a function, which is `truthy` because in javascript only `false, NaN, null, undefined, 0 , ""` are `false` and other all are `truthy`.!!!

And here  also  `!` comes in frond of function like `!function(){return true};`  soit will convert the `true` to `false`.

[Reference1](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) ,

---

[Reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

Comment: It has nothing to do with myVar containing a function already. Even without the () at the end, the ! turns the second example from a function declaration to a function expression because JavaScript thinks it needs to find the inverse of something. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341698/javascript-plus-sign-in-front-of-function-name

Comment: @DaveRoss thanks for your valid suggestions i  had updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

First snippet

```
var myVar = !function(){ return false; }( );
// myVar = false; because invocation ----^
alert(myVar); // !false = true
```

Second snippet

```
var myVar = !function(){return false};
// myVar = Function myVar = !(Function) and a Function is *truthy*
alert(myVar); // !true  = false
```

In the first snippet, you're calling it right away, so `myVar` is `false` and `!false` is obviously `true`.

In the second snippet however, you ain't calling the function. Instead, `myVar` is now a function, which is *truthy*. That is, it's *considered* `true`. So again `!true = false`.

Remember, in javascript, `false`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, `0` , `""` are *falsey* and everything else is *truthy*.

Comment: I Need bit more explanation on this, Could you please?

Comment: @User123 what did you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the !function statement. when you use the () at the end of a function, you actually say you want to use the return output of the function. you didn't use it with the last statement.

```js
var myVar = function(){return true}();
alert(myVar);   //true 
var myVar = function(){return false}();
alert(myVar);  //false
```