# What is the difference between these function types?

Tags: javascript

```
(function (foo) { alert(10); } ());

(function (foo) { alert(10); } )();
```

Both are anonymously invoked function, but there is a difference in the code structure. I am trying to understand the difference. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side note: You're never using the `foo` argument in those functions, no need to declare it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between them at all. The outer parens are just there to force the parser to treat `function` as the beginning of an *expression* rather than the beginning of a *declaration*; whether you put the `()` calling the resulting function inside or outside of them doesn't matter. You can even not use the outer parens at all:

```js
+function(foo) { alert(10); }();
```

The `+` *also* makes the parser expect an expression rather than a declaration.

More about this aspect of parsing in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13341710/157247).

Comment: "*There is no difference between them at all*". Don't tell Douglas Crockford that!! ;-)