# self executed function in jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Normally we'll do some of these :

first type

```
(function(){

}());
```

type 2

```
+function(){

}();
```

But today I saw this

```
$(run);

function run(){
//..
}
```

what is the different of that versus the earlier two?

Comment: `$(run)` is one of syntax used for [document-ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) hanlder

Comment: 1st and 2nd are IIFE.. second one is a safe guard for code minification.. 3rd one is document ready

Comment: So what's the difference between `(function(){` and `+function(){` ?

Comment: This [JavaScript plus sign in front of function name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341698/javascript-plus-sign-in-front-of-function-name) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third version is technically not the same as first two. The two first constructions are simply a way to write an expression which can be executed, since function declaration (statement starting with `function` keyword) cannot be invoked immediately.

The third is different. It is one of the jQuery document ready syntax. If the function is passed into `$` function it is either appended to a stack of callbacks to be called on DOMContentLoaded event if it hasn't occurred yet, or - it is called immediately.

Check the [jQuery's source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0ea8c32863af31fb5cfc184e8d513bbae35583e8/src/core/init.js#L100) code to see how it handles functions in this case. Abstract:

```
// ...
} else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {
    return rootjQuery.ready !== undefined ?
        rootjQuery.ready( selector ) :
        // Execute immediately if ready is not present
        selector( jQuery );
}
```

Comment: if in the beginning of my script i do $(function(){}); or document.ready, there is no point using the 3rd one right?

Comment: Yes, it's redundant in this case. You just call it directly `run()`.