# ES6 destructuring, dynamic assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let text, value;
if (typeof f == 'string') {
    text = value = f;
} else {
    let {
        text, value
    } = f;
}
```

Doing this creates two new vars (from the `else`), however if I write it like so:

```
let text, value;
if (typeof f == 'string') {
    text = value = f;
} else {
    {
        text, value
    } = f;
}
```

I receive a syntax error. What is the best approach here?

Comment: Alternatively, `const {text, value} = (typeof f === 'string') ? {text: f, value: f} : f;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need parens around the assignment:

```
let text, value;
if (typeof f == 'string') {
    text = value = f;
} else {
    ({                // ( at start
        text, value
    } = f);           // ) at end
}
```

([Live copy on Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=%22use%20strict%22%3B%0Alet%20text%2C%20value%3B%0Aif%20(typeof%20f%20%3D%3D%20'string')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20text%20%3D%20value%20%3D%20f%3B%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%2C%20value%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%3D%20f)%3B%0A%7D%0A).)

You need those parens for the same reason [you need parens or similar to immediately invoke a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13341710/157247): To tell the parser that it should expect an expression, not a statement. Without the parens, when it encounters the `{`, it thinks that's the beginning of a block. But unlike with the function, it has to be parens, not a leading unary `+`, `!`, etc. [like this](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=%22use%20strict%22%3B%0Alet%20text%2C%20value%3B%0Aif%20(typeof%20f%20%3D%3D%20'string')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20text%20%3D%20value%20%3D%20f%3B%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%2C%20value%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%3D%20f%3B%0A%7D%0A):

```
let text, value;
if (typeof f == 'string') {
    text = value = f;
} else {
    +{                 // <== Doesn't work like it does with IIFEs
        text, value
    } = f;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Minor note: The parentheses only need to surround the curly braces; the assignment itself can be outside.

Comment: @Zirak: No, the parens need to be around the *whole* assignment expression; it's an error otherwise: [bit.ly link to Babel repl (too long to paste in a comment)](http://bit.ly/1HGPapN). They even have a specific message for it: "You're trying to assign to a parenthesized expression, eg. instead of `({a}) = 0` use `({a} = 0)`" And if you think about it, that's not at all surprising: With the parens only around the `{}`, it looks like an object initializer in parens (because in ES6 you can use that shorthand form).

Comment: Didn't know Babel. thanks.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: :-) It's not immediately obvious from the links above, but that's just the REPL tool. Primarily, [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is a really powerful transpiler. You can use most of ES6 and it transpiles it to ES5. Of course, efficiency may go out the window with a transpiler...