# Can't get some JS syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

file.js:

```
(function(m) {
    //some
    //code
    //here
}(m))
```

I can't get what does this construction mean?

Comment: That is [IIFE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

That code defines a function inline and it immediately executes it.

Think about it by substituting the function for a variable:

```
(function(m) {
    //some
    //code
    //here
}(m))
```

Then that's the same as:

```
var f = function(m) {
    //some
    //code
    //here
}
(f(x))
```

But without having to define the `f`.

Comment: But why they use () surround function call?

Comment: @sector119: Because without them, the parser is in a state where seeing the keyword `function` will start a function *declaration*. To invoke it immediately, we need the parser to start a function *expression*, so we use parens (or a `+`, or a `!`, etc.) to put the parser in a state where only an expression, not a declaration, is valid. [More in this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13341710/157247)

Comment: The extra `()` makes it an expression rather than just a function definition which is required for it to work as desired.