# jQuery error on Custom Javascript variable in Google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Why am I getting an error when I run a jquery as a Custom javasript variable? The error description is `"Error at line 10, character 2: Parse error. ')' expected"`

```
function(){
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('button[class="panel__link panel__link--btb"]').on( 'click', function(e) {
       var $label = $( this ).parent().find("h2").text();
       return $label;
    });

  });
};
```

Please advise.

Regards,

Sree

Comment: That code, as quoted, has a syntax error: You can't have a function *declaration* with no name. In the position you've quoted it, `function` starts a function declaration. If there's more context, please show it -- at least enough that the code doesn't cause a syntax error just on its own. If this **is** what your code is, that's your answer. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155277/function-declaration-vs-function-expression).

Comment: try to remove function(){}

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last semicolon `;` on the last line:

```
function(){
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('button[class="panel__link panel__link--btb"]').on( 'click', function(e) {
 var $label = $( this ).parent().find("h2").text();
return $label;
});

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did some conceptual mistake, when you working with GTM. Custom variable should return some value when trigger is fired.

I think your initial goal in GTM is:

> Send some tag (to Universal analytics or something else) when user clicks on button `button[class="panel__link panel__link--btb"]`. This tag should contain some text information, which you can find like that `.parent().find("h2").text();`

If i am correct, then you should do  the following:

1. Go to Variables. Built-in variables-> Configure-> Enable `Click Element`
2. Go to Triggers -> New -> Type: All Elements -> `Click Element`:`matches CSS selector`:`button.panel__link.panel__link--btb`
3. Go to Variables. New -> Custom JavaScript: `function(){return {{Click Element}}.parent().find("h2").text();}` -> Name: 'H2 text'
4. Go to Tags. New -> Assign trigger from step #2.  -> Type: (you can choose what you need) -> And here you can use your variable `{{H2 text}}`, it will return necessary text

Answer (score -1):

The error is caused because there no name for the function. I think you are trying to do a Self Invoking function which should be

```
(function(){
   //your code
}());
```

Your code should be,

```
(function(){
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('button[class="panel__link panel__link--btb"]').on( 'click', function(e) {
      var $label = $( this ).parent().find("h2").text();
      return $label;
    });

  });
}());
```

Or

Remove the `function() {}` and simply execute the code with `.ready`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('button[class="panel__link panel__link--btb"]').on( 'click', function(e) {
      var $label = $( this ).parent().find("h2").text();
      return $label;
    });

});
```