# Are the parentheses enclosing "function incrementNumber()" optional?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm new to JavaScript and am trying to learn JavaScript closures. I have two versions of the same code, the only difference is that version 2 has parentheses enclosing the function. I have run both versions and they seem to produce identical results. I was wondering if the parentheses enclosing "function incrementNumber()" are optional?

Version 1:

```
var incrementFunctionVariable = function incrementNumber(){
    var clickCount = 0;
    return function (){
        return ++clickCount;
    }
}()
```

Version 2: parentheses enclosing "function incrementNumber()"

```
var incrementFunctionVariable = (function incrementNumber(){
    var clickCount = 0;
    return function (){
        return ++clickCount;
    }
})()

<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="alert(incrementFunctionVariable())" /><br>
```

Comment: They're optional *in that context*. If you wanted a standalone [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), i.e., if you didn't want to assign the return value to anything, you would need the parentheses (or a leading `!` or whatever).

Comment: There has to be *some* kind of operator before the `function` keyword ... that's the difference between a `function declaration` and a `function expression`.  The use of parens in *that* context are for the reader -- letting the human who reads the code know that it a IIFE.. and not a function to be called later.

Comment: P.S. Note that this isn't really related to closures, because whether or not those parentheses are required is not related to what the function actually does or what it returns.

Comment: Another note: In ES2015 `let` is an replacement for IIFEs, since it enables block scope.

Comment: @LUH3417: `let` is a replacement for **one small use case** of IIFEs. There are still plenty of others.

Comment: Side note: English is clearly not your first language (though your English is very good!), so I'll just mention that "parentheses" is a plural (one parenthesis [note the 'is' at the end], two parentheses ["es" at the end]). So "*Are* the parentheses..." not "Is the parentheses..." (In fact, what few issues there were with the English in the question seemd to relate mostly to plurals and subject/verb agreement, just FWIW. And again, your English is really good. I guarantee you it's much better than I can do in your native language.)

Comment: T.J. I disagree (partially). Scoping is the main purpose of IIFEs. What else do you mean? Private members? I don't use them.

Comment: @LUH3417: Let's say `let` combined with modules and inferred function names (once those are reliably in place on browsers) will largely do away with most use cases for IIFEs. :-)

Comment: Just for clarification: Inferred function names mean that ES6 compliant engines can infer the name of an anonymous function from its lexical position, `const foo = function() {}; foo.name === "foo";` yields `true`. This works for normal assignments too. @T.J. agreed.

Comment: Indeed, that they *must* assign names to functions created via "anonymous" function expressions in a large number of situations where in ES5 the functions would be nameless. Anyone wanting to know more, search [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) (or [the new one](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html)) for "SetFunctionName" to find those many and varied places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very similar to [*JavaScript plus sign in front of function name*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341698/javascript-plus-sign-in-front-of-function-name), but perhaps not quite a duplicate.

In that particular case, you don't need the parentheses you're referring to, but you do in some other cases.

In JavaScript, if the parser is expecting a statement or declaration and it sees the `function` keyword, it assumes it's a function declaration (or in ES2015, a function statement). Those are not expressions (although in JavaScript, expressions are valid where statements/declarations are expected). Function declarations/statements don't produce a value you can immediately use in your code.

But if the parser is expecting an expression (for instance, on the right-hand side of an `=`), `function` starts a function *expression*. A function *expression* does produce a value (a reference to the function) you can use immediately in your code.

The reason you see `()` around function expressions is that people are used to writing them when they invoke the function immediately:

```
// WON'T WORK
function() { alert("foo"); }();

// Works
(function() { alert("foo"); }());

// Works
(function() { alert("foo"); })();
```

They do that to change the state of the parser from expecting a statement/declaration to expecting an expression, so that `function` starts a function expression, and so has a resulting value, which they can then use to call the function via `()`.

You don't need to do that in your example because after the `=`, the parser is *already* expecting an expression. But even though it's not necessary, it's commonly done, perhaps because it's **really** easy to read past the `()` at the end. That is, this:

```
var foo = function foo() {
    // lots of stuff here
};
```

and this

```
var foo = function foo() {
    // lots of stuff here
}();
```

are *really* easy to confuse. Adding the `()` to the latter makes them less similar:

```
var foo = (function foo() {
    // lots of stuff here
})();
```

But it's not necessary, if people do that, it's habit and/or style.