# How to make a break in a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout, window.open

I want to make a break in a for loop in javascript.
My actually code is

```
<p id="1">The video opens</p>
        <script>
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        myWindow = window.open("VIDEO");
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "Wait";
        setTimeout(myWindow.close(), 10000);
    }

        </script>
```

The video should start in a new tab, plays 10 seconds, and then closes.
Then it starts again, plays anozher time 10 seconds and closes the video etc...
But the Timeout isn't a real timeout. It makes only the myWindow.close() comes 10 seconds later
That means, all 10 videos start, and then, 10 seconds later, one video closes.
How can I make it work right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're saying you want to do the ten videos *one at a time*.

If so, you can't use a `for` loop for this, you have to use either `setInterval` or a chained series of `setTimeout`. I'd go for the latter in this case:

```
// IIFE to keep our variables private
(function() {
    // Counter
    var i = 0;

    // Show the first video
    showVideo();

    // Function for showing the current video identified by `i`
    function showVideo() {
        var myWindow = window.open("VIDEO"); // Presumably use `i` here
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "Wait";
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Close the window
            myWindow.close();

            // Done yet?
            if (++i < 10) {
                // No, show the next video
                showVideo();
            }
        }, 10000);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Why there's at the beginning  a bracket (

Comment: @Korne127: It's one of the standard ways of creating an inline-invoked function expression (IIFE), see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13341710/157247) for details. If we just started with `function`, it would be a syntax error.

Comment: I have made the whole function away and changed it a little, but it workes great!

Answer (score -2):

Change setTimeout with setInterval function, setInterval function is made for loop, it's run every 10 seconds e.g. like you want.