# What is the difference between an expression and a statement in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, expression

What is the difference between a statement and a expression? How can i know each one is?

Why void transform this:

```
void function() {

}();
```

into an expression?

And why this works:

```
something((something) => something + 2);
```

and this don't:

```
something((something) => if (something) { something + 2 });
```

?

Thanks!!

Comment: `if` isn't a function, and has no return value, therefore you cannot assign the "result" of an `if` to something, because `if` HAS NO results.

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming? Or node.js for that matter....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Statements and expressions are different language units. What's probably tripping you up is that JavaScript, unlike some other languages, has what the spec calls [*ExpressionStatement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-expression-statement): It can treat any expression as a statement (but it cannot treat statements as expressions). So for instance, this is valid JavaScript:

```
flag && console.log("Hi there");
```

...whereas in (say) Java that wouldn't be valid, because while Java has some specific statements to allow for specific expression-like things (method calls, for instance), it doesn't have JavaScript's overall *ExpressionStatement*.

> Why `void` transform this:
>
> ```
> void function() {
>
> }();
> ```
>
> into an expression?

Because [`void` is an *operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-void-operator). It evaluates its operand (whatever follows it), and then sets its result to `undefined`. It's not at all related to the `void` that you see in languages like C, C++, Java, or C#. So the whole thing is an *ExpressionStatement*. The only reason you need the `void` there is that without it, when the parser is expecting to see a statement, the keyword `function` puts the parser into a state where it's expecting a function declaration, not an expression. (You can use *any* operator, not just `void`, to put the parser into expression state; [details in this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341698/javascript-plus-sign-in-front-of-function-name).)

> And why this works:
>
> ```
> something((something) => something + 2);
> ```
>
> and this don't:
>
> ```
> something((something) => if (something) { something + 2 });
> ```

Because of the way arrow functions are defined by the specification. There are two forms of arrow function:

- Ones with a *concise* body (no `{}`)
- Ones with a verbose body

Concise example:

```
array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

Equivalent verbose example:

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
    return a - b;
});
```

Arrow functions with concise bodies require that the body be an *expression* because, as you can see above, they return the result of the expression. You can't use a statement there for the same reason you can't use a statement other places an expression is required: A result value is needed for the implicit `return` statement. Your second example, translated to a verbose body, is this:

```
something((something) => {
    return if (something) { something + 2 };
});
```

...which demonstrates why it didn't work: You have an `if` after `return`, but the [`return` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-return-statement) requires an operand (expression) or statement terminator instead.

Answer (score 0):

### In short, expression refers to value, statement defines behavior.

---

### For a complete explanation you should always read the top voted answer: [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39836198/3043719)

---

Let me just show you some naive examples.

The following code define a `value`. It is a `statement` called `let statement` led by `let` keyword. Here `1` is an `expression`.

```js
// statement
// |---------|
   let n = 1 ;
//        |-|
//        expression
```

And this is `for statement` led by `for` keyword. It comes with some nested expressions and statements.

```js
//      expression(1)
//      |-----------|
   for (num in numArr) {                 //--+
                                         //  |
      sum += (num * 3); // statement(2)  //  |
//            |-----|                    //  |statement(1)
//            expression(2)              //  |
                                         //  |
   }                                     //--+
```

So a `statement` is an instruction unit telling computer **what to DO**. `for statement`, `while statement`, `if statement`, they are all **Actions**, in another word **Tasks**.

But for `expression`, **we are talking about values, valuables, objects, or some procedures that can produce a value, like function.**

```js
1 + 2
(2 + 3) * 5 === 25
new Foo()
```

So Javascript also has `function expression`. Because `function` is a `value`. In the following code,

1. The entire snippet is a statement.
2. Everything after `=` is an expression.
3. `return width * height;` is nested statement.
4. `width * height` is an expression.

```js
const rectArea = function(width, height) {
  return width * height;
};
```