# if statement in render method - react native

Tags: react-native

i would like to use `if` statement in the return of render method , what i mean is something like this :

```
export default class App extends Component 
{

   render()
   {
        return(
             <View>
               if(this.state.error)
               {
                 <View>
                       <Image source={{"error"}} />
                       <Text>An Error Happen</Text>
                   </View>
               }
               else
               {
                   <View>
                       <List dataArray={this.state.items}></List>
                   </View>
                }
              </View>
        );
   }

}
```

i can use ternary operator , but what i want is to use `if` statement if it possible

Comment: You cannot use JS inside JSX. You can put this in a helper function and render it in the return method.

Comment: [Read the documentation for React.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: @Envision good idea  , thank for replay

Comment: why the down vote ?

Comment: @Ali Because you should start by reading docs :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Background

What is the [difference between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343679/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement) a statement and expression

Specific to JavaScript:

[What is the difference between an expression and a statement in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-js)

[JavaScript: declarations vs expressions vs statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351924/javascript-declarations-vs-expressions-vs-statements)

`return` expects an expression as the argument. if *statements* are not expressions (makes sense, since statement is in the name).

The implementation details of JSX (that stuff with `<Tags>`, but in javascript) is also relevant. JSX is compiled into normal JavaScript.

```js
<MyButton color="blue" shadowSize={2}>
  Click Me
</MyButton>
```

compiles to

```js
React.createElement(
  MyButton,
  {color: 'blue', shadowSize: 2},
  'Click Me'
)
```

[documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

If you want to evaluate a JavaScript expression in JSX you need to enclose it in curly braces.

```js
const myButtonColor = 'blue'
//...
<MyButton color={myButtonColor} shadowSize={2}>
  Click Me
</MyButton>
```

## Back to the Question

Ways of accomplishing if-like functionality:

1. inline logical and (`&&`)
2. ternary operator (`?`)
3. `return` in if/else statements

Let's look at some examples:

#### Inline Logical And

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.state.error && <Text> There's an error! </Text>}
    </View>
  )
}
```

This method is the simplest and I recommend trying it first. It makes sense when you don't want to do anything if the condition evaluates to false. `&&` behaves a bit [different in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535647/logical-operators-in-javascript-how-do-you-use-them) than in other languages. When `this.state.error` evaluates to false, render returns this.state.error, which may have [unintended consequences](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) if `this.state.error` happens to be the empty string or `0`.

#### Ternary Operator

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.state.error ? <Text>Error!</Text> : <Text>No Error!</Text>}
    </View>
  )
}
```

The biggest problem with this is that the lines get long pretty quickly. You can get around this with parentheses.

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.state.error ? (
        <Text>Long, detailed error message</Text>
      ) : (
        <Text>No Error!</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}
```

You could alternatively use JavaScript strings declared before return along with this method.

#### Return in if Block

```js
render() {
  if(this.state.error) {
    return (<Text>Long, detailed error message</Text>)
  }
  else {
    return (<Text>No Error!</Text>)
  }
}
```

The problem with this method is if that if you have a long render method and a small conditional change, you will have to nearly repeat the render function in each if block. I generally use this method as a last resort.

Comment: Indeed it did. I just fixed it.

Comment: Cool :+1: Thanks for the answer, though!

Answer (score 8):

this is the simple one :

```
render()
   {
        return(
             <View>
               {this.state.error ?
                 (<View>
                       <Image source={{"error"}} />
                       <Text>An Error Happen</Text>
                 </View>)
               :
                 (<View>
                       <List dataArray={this.state.items}></List>
                 </View>)
                }
              </View>
        );
   }
```

maybe can help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You should try somthing like this:

```
export default class App extends Component {
render() {
  if(this.state.error)
  {
    return (
     <View>
       <Image source={{"error"}} />
       <Text>An Error Happen</Text>
     </View>
     )
  }
  else {
    return (
      <View>
        <List dataArray={this.state.items}></List>
      </View>
     );
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
 render()
   {
        return(
             <View>
               {this.state.error && 
                 <View>
                       <Image source={{"error"}} />
                       <Text>An Error Happen</Text>
                   </View>
               }
               {!this.state.error &&
                   <View>
                       <List dataArray={this.state.items}></List>
                   </View>
                }
              </View>
        );
   }
```

Comment: what i want to use `if` , but it seem to be not possible

Comment: you can not use `if` within a return block

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to take advantage of js in this case:

```
{ this.state.error &&
   <View>
    <Text>show error</Text>
   </View>
}
{ !this.state.error &&
   <View>
    <Text>all good</Text>
   </View>
}
```

It can look better than ternary in some cases.