# Javascript: Syntax creating private object properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties, private

due to learning new things I came across how to make things private and public. The basic idea to me is clear. But just in terms of how it is built I got a specific question:

```
var NOW = (function(){
    var privateVariable = 5;
    var privateFunction = function(){};
    return{
        publicVariable: 4,
        publicFunction: function(){}
    };
})();
```

So my question is why is function wrapped inside brackets (parentheses)?

`var NOW =`**`(`**`function(){...}`**`)`**`();`

Comment: That is IIFE, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: What is that second part? Is it react jsx?

Comment: @RobertMoskal: I think it was just an atttempt at emphasizing the `()` in question.

Comment: There is no second part to it, I just came up with this code to show my question. The question is answered pretty well already, thx to everybody

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're optional in that code, this also works fine:

```
var NOW = function(){
    var privateVariable = 5;
    var privateFunction = function(){};
    return{
        publicVariable: 4,
        publicFunction: function(){}
    };
}();
```

People are in the habit of wrapping functions that they're going to immediately invoke in `()` because if you *aren't* assigning the result to something (or similar), it's necessary to tell the parser that the `function` keyword is starting a function *expression* rather than a function *declaration*. E.g., this is not okay:

```
function() { alert("foo"); }();
```

Because when the parser encounters `function` where it could be expecting a statement, declaration, or expression, it assumes it starts a declaration. So we do this:

```
(function() { alert("foo"); })();
```

or this:

```
(function() { alert("foo"); }());
```

or any of several other things (see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341698/javascript-plus-sign-in-front-of-function-name)) to put the parser in the mode where it's expecting an expression, not a statement or declaration.

Comment: Very well explained and very clear on what and why this convention is being used though it is not necessary in this case. Cheers