# What Does This JQuery Code Doing - !function($) and var = var => var =>

Tags: jquery

Here is a section of relevant code:

```
!function($){
    const figure = name => f => $(`<figure data-name="${name}"><img src="${URL.createObjectURL(f)}"><figcaption><input type=checkbox checked><br>${f.name}</figcaption></figure>`).data("f",f);

 $(document).on("change", "[data-preview-to]", function() {
        $($(this).data("preview-to")).append($.map(this.files, figure(this.name)));
        $(this).replaceWith(this.outerHTML);
***OTHER CODE FOR SUBMIT****
 }(jQuery);

HTML
 <input type="file" data-preview-to="#preview" multiple="" name="fileToUpload[]">
```

First question, the "!function($)", to me this says, I am not a function, since "!" is NOT, but that cannot be it since why would you declare a function, that is not a function, then I thought well, it could be saying "do this, even if the document is not ready" since (I think) function($), is the document ready shorthand.

However, the function ending, has a (jquery), which is needed, if I remove that, the code fails, so this must be doing something, that is not fully JQuery.

Second Question, is the variable "figure", the way I read it, and make no sense is "declare figure as a constant, take the value of name, push it into f then push all of it into the HTML code. However, I do not see how "f", gets assigned. I know it is coming from the "$.map(this.files, figure(this.name))", but it looks like the only thing that is getting sent to figure is the name (fileToUpload[]) of the HTML input tag.

What is this code saying and doing?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is just an *inline-invoked function expression*. The `!` is there to shift the parser from expecting a statement to expecting an expression, so that `function` starts a function expression rather than function declaration (which is why we can call it immediately). Details on that [in this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341698/javascript-plus-sign-in-front-of-function-name). `jQuery` is passed in by using `()` after the end of the function, and received as the `$` parameter.

`figure` is an ES2015+ (aka "ES6") [*arrow function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (specifically, an arrow function returning an arrow function, which contains a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) [the thing in backticks with `${...}` in it]). In this case, since this particular function doesn't use `this` or `arguments` or a couple of other things, it's roughly equivalent to this ES5 and earlier code:

```
var figure = function(name) {
    return function(f) {
        return $('<figure data-name="' + name + '"><img src="' + URL.createObjectURL(f)' + "><figcaption><input type=checkbox checked><br>' + f.name + '</figcaption></figure>').data("f",f);
    };
};
```

Comment: Looks like I have some homework. Was reading about all that stuff, this may be a little advanced, yet for me, so this is going to hurt the head a bit.

Answer (score 1):

**!function(){}()**

`!function(){}(argument);` means instantly calling created function.

Function declaration `function(){}` returns `undefined`. If we try to instant call this function

```
function () {} ()
```

It will throw SyntaxError. By using ! operator before the function, js understands it as an expression and runs function successfully

```
!function () {} ()
```

**=> Arrow functions**

```
const figure = name => f => $()

// is equal to 
const figure = function(name){
   return function(f){
       return $();
   }
}
```

Arrow functions allows to write short code. Arrow functions consists of argument head and body like in normal functions.

```
(arg1, arg2) => {
    return 4;
}
```

No more need to write `function`. 
Arguments are passed by standard way, with brackets like this `(arg1, arg2) => {}`, or if there is only one argument - there can be only argument `arg => {}`.

Code in body can be usual "block body", like in normal functions. If there is only one - return expression, function may have "concise body"

```
(arg1, arg2) => return 4;
```

So, if you have only one argument and one body expression, arrow function may take short but unusual form

```
var sqr = x => x*x;

// equal to
var sqr = function(x){
    return x*x;
}
```