# tilde ~ in front of anonymous function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tilde

if I run the following code:

```
~ function() {
alert('I am new here');
}();
```

the page alerts: 'I am new here'.
however if I try to run:

```
function() {
alert('I am new here');
}();
```

I get syntax error.

I can't find any explanation of tilde (~) that would explain this situation.

Comment: In this context, `~` is being used for the same thing `!` is in the linked [*JavaScript plus sign in front of function name*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341698/javascript-plus-sign-in-front-of-function-name) question; its answers apply.

Comment: Thank you!, exactly what I was looking for. How can I +1 your comment ?

Comment: You can't yet, but no worries! You will at some point: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges