# How to get my anonymous function to return a value instead of a function?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

My code:

```
var host_choice = function(){
    var choice;
    do {
        choice = shuffled_list[random_choice()];
    } while (choice == "car" || choice == player_choice);

    return choice;  
};
```

Here `host_choice` is a function which I would have to call. But I am unsure how to make it a variable containing `choice`. I know I am missing something basic here, but how to do it?

Side note: my `shuffled_list` contains 3 elements. And I want my `host_choice` variable to contain neither the element `car` nor the `player_choice` is there a "fancier" way of doing this?

Comment: just invoke it...

Comment: `host_choice();`

Comment: Looks like an [IIFE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) would make the trick

Comment: @taguenizy this was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke it directly.

```
var host_choice = (function(){
  var choice;
  do {
      choice = shuffled_list[random_choice()];
  } while (choice == "car" || choice == player_choice);

  return choice;  
})();
```

This is an example of [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). It is very handy for various reasons, such as modularity in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You'd call it, with `()` after it:

```
var host_choice = function(){
    var choice;
    do {
        choice = shuffled_list[random_choice()];
    } while (choice == "car" || choice == player_choice);

    return choice;  
}(); // <====
```

Note that that means it will only ever be run once, since you don't keep a reference to the function anywhere.

You'll frequently see this written with `()` around the function part, too:

```
var host_choice = (function(){
    var choice;
    do {
        choice = shuffled_list[random_choice()];
    } while (choice == "car" || choice == player_choice);

    return choice;  
})(); // <====
```

In your case, that's completely a matter of style, you don't need them. **If** you weren't using the return value, though, you'd need them so the parser didn't think the `function` keyword was starting a function declaration. (Which is where style comes in: Some people prefer to always include them even when they aren't strictly necessary, since they're necessary *sometimes*.) Details on that bit in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13341710/157247).