# What does () do besides creating a self invoking block in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've only really seen this used in

```
(function () {
    // more code...
})()
```

and basically it works as to prevent codes getting executed before the entire block of codes between the first `()` was loaded and the second `()` is just so we can invoke the function inside the first `()`.

Is there any other usage for `()`?

Comment: Reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) is always useful.

Comment: ok, how does you invoke a function?

Comment: It's just a function call, like any other.

Comment: The "prevent codes getting executed" explanation is wrong. The parentheses turn the function into an expression so that it can be called with the second pair of parentheses. `+function() {}()` or [whatever else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13341710) would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you're asking. `()` calls a function without arguments.

```js
(function () {
  console.log('Hi, I\'m in the function.');
})();
```

is the same as:

```js
function test () {
  console.log('Hi, I\'m in the function.');
}
test(); // call the function without any arguments
```

The first snippet demonstrates an IIFE (immediately-invokes function expression), which is used to create a new scope. Variables declared inside the IIFE are invisible outside the IIFE.

That's the only situation where you have empty `()`. Of course, if the `()` are not empty, they serve as a grouping operator: `(3 + 4) * 5`.

This grouping operator is also used in the IIFE example above: the function is wrapped in `()` to indicate that the `function` key word does not start a **function declaration** (which requires a name), but a **function expression**, which does not require a name. The following would cause a syntax error:

```js
function () {
  console.log('Hi, I\'m in the function.');
}(); // SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
```

That's because the parser sees the `function` and thinks it's a function declaration. To tell the parser that it's a function expression, we can use operators that can only be used with expressions:

- `(function () {})()`
- `+function () {}()`
- `-function () {}()`
- `~function () {}()`