# What does the bitwise operator do before a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, bitwise-operators

I have seen the bitwise operator used in a self calling function, see below example, so I have a simple question, what does it do?

```js
~(function() {

        alert("Hello World");

    })();
```

Comment: it does nothing special in this case - that's actually redundant ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341698/javascript-plus-sign-in-front-of-function-name

Comment: I'm doubtful that's the real code. For the `~` to have any meaning, the function in question would have to return something.

Comment: `~function() {
    alert("Hello World");
}();` is an alternative to `(function() {
    alert("Hello World");
})();` - but what you wrote is redundant

Comment: Well, ~undefined becomes -1  so it does *something*.

Comment: but the result is discarded, so it does nothing special or relevant or useful - and it is redundant

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Not quite. Every JS function returns _something_, even if it's just the default `undefined`. And `~(undefined)` is `-1`. It has meaning. It just doesn't have *purpose*.

Comment: by the way, you could also use `!`, `+` or `-` with the same effect - it's a way to create an IIFE

Comment: it forces the expression to evaluate, as `void` would do (with this only use case).

Comment: the most common IIFE pattern is `;(function() { ...code...})();` - yes, leading `;` "to be sure"

Comment: @NinaScholz - I did not know about `void`

Comment: @Amadan - Well, if we're going to be pedantic, a JavaScript function doesn't always return something -- but *calling* the function always produces a value (provided it doesn't throw); if the function didn't return anything, the value produced by calling it is `undefined`. The spec actually differentiates falling off the end of the function vs. using `return` and, for the former, fills in the `undefined` later. (Details in and around [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist).) But it's fairly extreme pedantry at that point. :-)