# ! function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I apologize for my stupid question, I am not good at javascript and angularjs. I've been referencing the code of some projects, and I'm really confused about this, what it actually is !function(a,b,c){}(x,y,z). I have never seen it before. I am not good at javascript nor angularjs. Thanks for all the help!

```
!function (e, n, t) {
    "use strict";
    // code
}(window, angular, jQuery)
```

Comment: Related: [JavaScript plus sign in front of function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13341698)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hacky way to immediately execute an anonymous function. If you were to define it normally (line starting with `function`, then it would immediately hoist the function as a *function statement* and force you to call it normally. Since the ! is in front of it, that lets the compiler evaluate it as a *function expression*, which can be invoked immediately. The exclamation mark here is the boolean `not`. Parenthesis or a plus sign would also work.

This would be equivalent code:

```
(e,n,t) => { /** */ }(window, angular, jQuery);
```

as would

```
(function (e,n,t) { /** */ })(window, angular, jQuery);
```

since the parenthesis will make the line be evaluated as an expression as well.

The anonymous function is being defined, and then called with the parameters `window, angular, jQuery`, which become `e,n,t` inside the function body.

Side note: I would not recommend writing functions like this, since it's uncommon syntax

Comment: @A Herbig Thanks for your help. I've come to understand this better, actually I was confused when I saw it at first. Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: I also mistook it for a boolean at first, but that doesn't seem to be the case for the function I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

it just simply tell the js to ignore this function and

it make it undefined Like This:

```
    function Demo(){
    console.log('log something');}
```

OutPut Will Be :

> log something

**But** If You Put A **`!`** Before The Function The Result Would Be:

> Demo is not defined

Comment: @Yesterday check out this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for your attached link, I will learn more about it. Wish you a good day!