# TypeError when calling jQuery.validate's showErrors function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

**Answer** It turned out to be very simple. Some time after I wrote the code, another developer added a form to the navbar for logging in. At this point, the code...

```
$('form').validate().showErrors({"Amount":"Bleah"})
```

...now affected two forms. As the log-in form was first in the HTML, I guess that got handled first, and threw the exception. By changing the code to...

```
$('#donateForm').validate().showErrors({"Amount":"Bleah"})
```

...it works fine. Thanks to all for the replies.

---

I'm having a problem adding errors to a form using `jQuery.validate`. If I load a page with the following...

```
<form id="donateForm">
  <div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="Amount" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Amount</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10 input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-pound-sign"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="Amount" name="Amount" class="form-control" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

...and then call the following from the console...

```
$('form').validate().showErrors({"Amount":"Bleah"})
```

...then I get the following error...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
>      at $.validator.highlight (jquery.validate.js:344)
>      at $.validator.defaultShowErrors (jquery.validate.js:912)
>      at $.validator.showErrors (jquery.validate.js:546)
>      at anonymous:1:22

I had a look at line 546 of `jQuery.validate.js`, and it was this...

```
this.defaultShowErrors();
```

...inside the `showErrors` function. This doesn't mean anything to me, but might help someone else work out what's going wrong.

Anyone any ideas? I realise I haven't given you much, but as `showErrors` is a function built in to `jQuery.validate`, I'm not sure what else is relevant.

Comment: do you have `form` tag or you did not include it in the question?

Comment: @AntihypeBird Yes, I do have a `form` tag. It's a long form, so I didn't include it all. I'll update the question to clarify this.

Comment: @AntihypeBird I updated the question, as it seems to be a very basic one, and can be reproduced very easily

Comment: Funny, it's working perfectly fine for me:  https://jsfiddle.net/318c94wa/

Comment: See this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9354233/594235